All-black, yet like green to red
Inspired by Prim3numbah's puzzle.
Which option from A-E should replace the question mark?


Hint 1:

 Focus on the top row. For the avoidance of doubt, I will say that the left isolated dot belongs to the graph below it; the central isolated dot belongs to the graph to its right; and the right isolated dot belongs to the graph to its right.

Hint 2:

 There is the actual answer, which is one of the choices.

 And then there's the "bigger answer", hidden in plain sight. Also, two of its meanings are used in this puzzle.

Hint 3:

 In the title, I couldn't partner red with orange, or with yellow, etc. I also couldn't partner green with orange, or with yellow, etc.

 I could have partnered orange with blue, though.


I think it's much better to have the knowledge tag there. Apologies for not putting it sooner.

The answer is

 D

Because

 You need to take the complement/inverse of each graph, i.e. connect the dots which are not connected in the original and leave out those which are connected in the original. This spells out "COMPLEMEN", and the missing T can be made with option D. This is hinted by "green to red", which are complementary colors.


Yes indeed! Am I correct in assuming that Hint 3 was what finally helped?

@oAlt Yes, after reading hint 3 I understood what was going on, certainly a "Why didn't I think of this earlier" moment.
